# Know dates in a month in which a day occurs in c

Tags: c

Im trying to print the dates in a month in which a day occurs. In order to do so, I need to get integer values for the days like 0 for a Sunday, 1 for a Monday, 2 for a Tuesday etc. How do I do that in C? I seem to get errors whenever I try.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(){
int days[]={0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
  int year, day, month, date, a, y, m, s, i, b=0;
  char week[7][10] ;

 strcpy(week[0], "Sunday") ;
 strcpy(week[1], "Monday") ;
 strcpy(week[2], "Tuesday") ;
 strcpy(week[3], "Wednesday") ;
 strcpy(week[4], "Thursday") ;
 strcpy(week[5], "Friday") ;
 strcpy(week[6], "Saturday") ; 
 //char *week[]={"Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday",
            //"Thrusday","Friday","Saturday"};
  printf("Enter the day:");
  scanf("%s",week[i]);
  printf("Enter the month:");
  scanf("%d",&month);
  printf("Enter the year:");
  scanf("%d",year);
  if(year%4==0&&year%100!=0||year%400==0)
  days[2]==
  29;
  else
  days[2]==28;

  //for(i=1;i<7;i++)
  //week[i]=i;
  //i=i+1;
  week[0]==0;
  week[1]==1;
  week[2]==2;
  week[3]==3;
  week[4]==4;
  week[5]==5;
  week[6]==6;

  //algorithm from http://www.tondering.dk/claus/cal/chrweek.php#calcdow
  a = (14 - month) % 12;
  y = year - a;
  m = month + (12 * a) - 12;

  date = (week[i] + y + (y / 4) - (y / 100) + (y / 400) + ((31 * m) / 12)) % 7 ;
  printf("%d",date);

  for(day=1; day<=days[month] ;day++)
  {
   date=date+7;
   date++;
  }
  return 0;
   }
```

Comment: You should share the errors you're getting

Comment: If I use the for loop in the comments i get something like [Error] incompatible types in assignment of 'int' to 'char [10]' but if I do week[0]==0 I get [Error] ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]

Comment: You should put the complete error message in the question.  The error message would also show the line numbers.

Comment: @Dan Oh yeah. I'm so sorry. C:\TURBOC3\BIN\4OUTPUT.C In function 'int main()':
32 10 C:\TURBOC3\BIN\4OUTPUT.C [Error] incompatible types in assignment of 'int' to 'char [10]'
35 12 C:\TURBOC3\BIN\4OUTPUT.C [Error] ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
 This error persists upto line 40.

Answer (score 1):

In the first scanf, i doesnt have a value. the week[0], week[1] and so on, are arrays of of chars. What do you want to do by comparing them with an int?? (week[0]==0.... ).

```
  declare a char[10] wordday;
  printf("Enter the day:");
  scanf("%s",wordday);




  for(i=0;i<7;i++)
      if(strcmp(wordday,week[i])==0)
      {
      printf("%d",i);
      break;
      }
```

Comment: Could you perhaps expand on this? What I want is to get the value 0 when the user input is Sunday.

Comment: @Mango, maybe it's not obvious to you, but what @Kristjan is doing here is  collecting a day name from the user and then comparing their input to the day names in `week[]` to find the "weekday number" corresponding to that weekday name.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has the signs of not being carefully read and analyzed by the programmer - no offence intended, it's just part of the process of learning to program.  The solution?  Make a copy of this and cut out all the code that's not absolutely critical to test the core of your program, then build up from there. Build test cases for the code you may not understand that run *in isolation*, so you have confidence in the pieces of code that you're bringing together in your program.  Read the errors, *google* the errors, and understand them too.  Only when you include understanding of errors in the scope of learning a programming language can you become fluent in that language.  Errors always mean something, and their messages are specific and informative.

For example, this bit of code:

```
  char week[7][10] ;

 strcpy(week[0], "Sunday") ;
 strcpy(week[1], "Monday") ;
 strcpy(week[2], "Tuesday") ;
 strcpy(week[3], "Wednesday") ;
 strcpy(week[4], "Thursday") ;
 strcpy(week[5], "Friday") ;
 strcpy(week[6], "Saturday") ; 
 //char *week[]={"Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday",
            //"Thrusday","Friday","Saturday"};
```

I'm always skeptical when I see valid, and more succinct, code commented out and replaced with brute force approaches.  It usually means the programmer doesn't understand the errors they are seeing, so they're cutting out bits of code they don't entirely understand and replacing with a more straightforward or explicit approach, thereby missing a valid opportunity to improve their understanding of the language.

Here's the minimal example I put together to prove to myself ( and the readers! ) that the commented invocation works well, and is way more straightforward:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char**argv){
  char *week[]={
    "Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday",
    "Thrusday","Friday","Saturday"
  };
  for( int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    printf("%s\n", week[i]);
  return 0;
}
```

See what I did there?  I built a test program to test *only* the bit of code I want to understand better.  Creating minimal proofs of concept of only a few lines is something I do very frequently when learning a new language.

Now let's talk about this chunk of code.

```
 //for(i=1;i<7;i++)
  //week[i]=i;
  //i=i+1;
  week[0]==0;
  week[1]==1;
  week[2]==2;
  week[3]==3;
  week[4]==4;
  week[5]==5;
  week[6]==6;
```

Remember, `week` is a 7 element array of `char*`, or string, values.  If you're getting compile errors about incompatible types when you use the `for` loop version, it's because you're trying to set it to a number.

I'm not sure what the `i=i+1` is supposed to be doing in there.  The way the code is written, that's outside of the `for` loop (without `{}` curly brackets, a `for` loop only iterates with *one* line of code, remember).  So you iterate over i in the range of 0 to 6, and then stop when it's 7, and outside the for loop set it to 8.  Remember, `for` loops in C have a built in method for incrementing, which you're already using ( `i++` in the `for` arguments ).  You don't have to increment yourself.

The uncommented version, you have an *comparison* operator `==`, not the *assignment* operator `=`.   Your code doesn't assign any values, it  *compares* `"Sunday"` to `0`, `"Monday"` to 1, etc.  You're not doing anything with the results, so even if these comparisons *were* valid, these lines are completely without effect.

I'm actually a little baffled  what you're trying to do with `week` in general.  First you set it to the weekday names - OK, that's valid.  Then you attempt to set each value to its index ( `week[0] = 0`, etc).  This would be a really pointless array; you may as well just use the index and skip the array entirely if it's just going to give you the index value back.  Finally, you don't seem to actually use `weeks` as part of your code or algorithm, other than the following snippet which simply saves a value *into* it ( erroneously, I might add), so I'm not sure why it's there at all.

```
printf("Enter the day:");
scanf("%s",week[i]);
```

Better read the doc on `scanf`.  You're having them enter a day, and you're storing that string the enter into the string at pointer `week[i]`.  Wait a second, wasn't `week` going to be your weekday number to weekday name lookup table?  Why would you use it for the day the user entered?  I think you know what you're *trying* to do here, but that's not what's happening.

What I'd recommend to you is to pare this code down to some thing minimal and easily verifiable, make sure the core functionality is working, and then grow from there.  In this case, you should start by removing the `scanf` statements all together, and hard code the inputted day, month and year.  Then run those hard coded inputs through your algorithm and see if you get the expected results.  Once you get the algorithm proven, you can add the `scanf` statements and support for the named days (@Kristjan Kica's answer helps with that part).  You'll end up with working code far faster if you focus on small pieces that are assembled to create the final product, than if you just power through the entire program  all at once, without really understanding it.

Comment: Yeah, I'll try and do that. Thank you so much. This really helps a lot. Thank you.